# How to wash a shirt with foam inserts?

Tags: clothing, laundry

I am a first-time buyer of boohoo clothing and the [shirt](https://us.boohoo.com/twist-front-crop-t-shirt/FZZ20447-3.html?color=667) I purchased comes with foam inserts to keep the shape of sleeve. The inserts are stitched in and are not removable. Since it is foam I assume the inserts absorb a lot of water. The website claims it is machine-washable, but from my research, people have mixed reviews on washing boohoo clothing.  With the foam inserts, I am even more skeptical.  Is it okay to machine-wash and hang dry the shirt? Should I hand-wash it and avoid the foam or inserts? Or just hand-wash normally?

Comment: When you bought it, did it have washing instructions?

Comment: @KenGraham I checked the label, but I didn't see washing instructions on there.

Comment: Show a picture of the label(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to wash a shirt with foam inserts?**

When in true doubt, hand wash it!

Being a quasi professional tailor, and have worked and washed many different types of fabrics. Still, I have to seek council from trusted friends about various types of new materials.

Never worn or used **boohoo clothing** before, but I think it would be better to hand wash it, in lieu of using a washing machine.

Nevertheless, you could use a washing machine. In that case, follow the washing instructions and recommended temperature settings. However, if possible wash it separately and on a gentle cycle.

Let it hang dry, just to be extra safe!

The big problem with these new types of clothing apparels is that there are dozens of different types of foams on the market!